# Update led to black screen/cant log in to Ubuntu

Tags: updates

I got a message asking to update Ubuntu and started the update.

Things were going fine but suddenly I got a blankscreen and, after a long wait and the laptop going quiet besides the fan, I had to switch it off.

I switched it back on and just get the console, which I have little/no experience of. I tried sudo apt-get update as suggested elsewhere but it doesn't seem to work (just says it couldn't download most things). Also tried other suggestions elsewhere, like sudo init 3 and sudo init 5. Just says 'PolicyKit daemon disconnected from the bus. We are no longer a registered authentication agent.'

What can I do? I am very new to Ubuntu and the laptop came with it preinstalled. Very worried about losing work on there.

Thanks,
Aled

PS -
I should've said - when I turn it on, I get the Dell logo as normal, then the Ubuntu logo as normal, but before the usual log-in screen, it goes into text with my computer name and 'tty1', and asks for my login and password. After typing them in, I can do commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Try type `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: That got my to where I put in my password (including the start up sound), but it doesn't look like it normally does and, when I type in my password, the screen goes blank and then it takes me back to where I put in my password (repeating the sound)...